# Drilldown with MySQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

How do i add drilldown function in my column highchart?

```php
<script>
drilldown: {
series: [
<?php
for ($j=0; $j < count($service) ; $j++) {
name: '<?php echo $service[$j]; ?>',
id: '<?php echo $service[$j]; ?>',
data: [
<?php 
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(stamp, '%b %d')) as dateDays from entries where sid = '$arrSID[$j]'");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
$days[] = $row['dateDays'];
}
for ($k=0; $k < count($days) ; $k++) {
$sql1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalDayVote FROM entries where DATE_FORMAT(stamp, '%b %d') = '$days[$k]' && sid = '$arrSID[$j]'");
while ($row1 = $sql1->fetch_assoc()) {
$dayVote = $row1['totalDayVote']; ?>
['<?php echo $days[$k]; ?>', <?php echo ($dayVote); ?>],
<?php
}
}
?>
]
}
?>
</script>
```

The result is i get the first chart that display title of my services and when i click on one of the services it will drilldown entries by day of that specific service.

Comment: Hi @Kael Jordins, Please check the docs about drilldown: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown and the asynch drilldown example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0s37fcL2/. Please let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Hello sir, That's the one i followed first but i can't do it because i want to get data from my database then each service has their own corresponding entry of data then when i click one of my service in the chart it will drilldown all entry by day.

Comment: You need to keep the same code structure and change only the data entries.

Comment: Okay i will try. Thanks.

Comment: Sir @ppotaczek do you have any example of this drilldown that has data entries. I don't know how to declare them. Can't find some on google also on highcharts docs. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sir @ppotaczek i have error showing Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14

Comment: It means that you have string value in data. You probably need to parse string values to numbers.

Comment: sir @ppotaczek i have done it all. But it's annoying because it display also the dates that has 0 values. How to remove those dates?

Comment: Please reproduce that problem in some online code editor.